# Refreshed Configuration in Environment BUT not in @ConfigurationProperty Bean

Tags: configuration, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a bean listening to `ApplicationEvent<EnvironmentChangeEvent>`
The same bean also has a reference to a property bean, say SysConfig (instance of a bean with `@ConfigurationProperties`)

I issue a call to refresh endpoint (/refresh).

Is it right to expect the refreshed/rebinded SysConfig bean in `onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentChangeEvent evt)` ?

I am not getting the refreshed/rebinded property bean in the event handling method.BUT the `Environment.getProperty()` is reflecting the change.

Is it because my event-handler is called before `ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder` event-handler ?

How to fix this ? I need refreshed SysConfig property bean.

Versions: spring v4.1.6, boot v1.2.3, cloud-config v1.0.1

Comment: is this similar to https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13394 ?

Comment: I guess you need to add `@RefreshScope` on your `SysConfig`

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll The ConfigurationProperties bean should already be in `RefreshScope ` automatically, right ? Do we need to explicitly annotate it ?

Comment: I explicitly annotated the SysConfig with `@RefreshScope`. Still no change. And /beans endpoint states the SysConfig is in singleton scope. Is that how it works?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll I managed to get updated `SysConfig` by calling `ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.rebind`. Not sure if it is the right way

Comment: I just ran into this as well. I don't have a solution but I did find part of the cause. I noticed that my bean annotated with @ConfigurationProperties was created before the ConfigurationPropertiesBeans post processor.  The ConfigurationPropertiesBeans post processor maintains the list of ConfigurationPropertties beans to rebind.